# Excel VBA: Compiler Errors

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, duplicates

So yesterday I posted my first SO question, and it went down like a ton of bricks. However I've picked myself up, dusted myself off, and hopefully this question will be more acceptable... :-)

I am trying to remove data duplicates from a list of Health Questionnaires I have to monitor, but the tricky bit I was struggling with was finding a duplicate in one column, AND then checking that the data on the same row, for the 3 adjacent columns were also duplicates. Storing the searched for 'duplicated row' was the bit that was throwing me off.

Here's some code I've cobbled together from other similarly-functioning scripts. I'm now in debug mode and keep getting errors thrown up... I don't have much experience of VBA, so i'm running out of options.

I'm currently getting type mismatch errors with the variable `g`, and also `firstAddress`. Why are these causing problems???

Can I call `firstAddress.Row` or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Here's the snippet:

```
g = .Find(Range("G" & i).Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not g Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = g.Address
                dupRow = firstAddress.Row
```

And here's the whole code below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub FindCpy()
Dim lw As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim dupRow As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim firstAddress As Integer


'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Used to narrow down the logical operators for duplicates
Dim rngFirst As Range

'Set the ranges
rngFirst = Range("G" & 1, "G" & lw)

Set sh = Sheets("Completed")
lw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lw 'Find duplicates from the list.
    If Application.CountIf(Range("A" & i & ":A" & lw), Range("A" & i).Text) = "Complete" Then

    'if COMPLETE, check the rest of the sheet for any 'in progress' duplicates...
    With Worksheets("Still In Progress").rngFirst
        g = .Find(Range("G" & i).Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not g Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = g.Address
            dupRow = firstAddress.Row
            If Range("H" & dupRow).Text = Range("H" & i).Text _
            And Range("I" & dupRow).Text = Range("I" & i).Text _
            And Range("J" & dupRow).Text = Range("J" & i).Text Then

        'select the entire row
        Range.EntireRow.Select

        'copy the selection
        Selection.Cut

        'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
        Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")
        objNewSheet.Select

        'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
        Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'delete the initial row
        rngCell.EntireRow.Delete

        Set g = .FindNext(g)
            Loop While Not g Is Nothing And g.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks pnuts, that's great. I thought that g would be returning an integer, but you're right, the range is really what it's looking for.

NOW it's telling me that Range.EntireRow.Select is invalid because the argument isn't optional... This line of code has worked before... 

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've swapped it out for ActiveCell. I'm hoping that will do what I want it to do... Fingers crossed.

You're 2 for 2 though, so go get a coffee. ;-)

Comment: Best to avoid `ActiveCell` and `Select` methods. `Range.EntireRow.Select` fails because `Range` requires an address or index arguments, you may try simply `g.EntireRow.Select` since `g` is a Range object. Otherwise, qualify the range you want to select, like @pnuts says.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code carefully. There were a number of problems. Some of these I think I was able to fix - there was one where I guessed what you intended to do, but for one of them I just marked it; you need to explain what you were trying to do, as you are deleting a range that you never defined...

The first problem is with the line:

```
If Application.CountIf(Range("A" & i & ":A" & lw), Range("A" & i).Text) = "Complete" Then
```

The `CountIf` function returns a number; you are comparing this number with the string "Complete". I don't think you can ever get past this line, so the rest of the code (whether correct or not) will not execute. Not entirely clear what you are trying to do in this line, as I'm not sure when a line will be marked "Complete" - but assuming that you are interested in executing the rest of the code if the cell in `A & i` has the string "Complete" in it, then you probably want to do

```
If Range("A" & i).Text = "Complete" Then
```

There were a number of `If - Then`, `With`, and `Loop` structures that were not properly terminated with a matching `End`. I have tried to remedy this - make sure I did it right. Note that using proper indentation really helps to find problems like this. The space bar is your friend...

Since the `Find` method returns an object, the correct way to use the function is

```
Set g = .Find(Range("G" & i).Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Apart from that - use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, and define variables with the most restrictive (correct) type that you can. When I did this I found the error I could not correct - with the `rngCell` variable that was neither declared, nor ever set... It shows just how helpful it can be. Also good for catching typos - VBA will happily let you write things like

myVar = 1
   MsgBox myVra + 1

The message will be `1`, not `2`, because of the typo... The fact that `Explicit` should even be an *option* is one of the many inexplicable design decisions made by the VBA team.

Here is your code "with most of the errors fixed". At least like this it will compile - but you must figure out what to do with the remaining error (and I can't be sure I guessed right about what you wanted to do with the cell marked "Complete").

Comments welcome.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCpy()
Dim lw As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim dupRow As Integer
Dim g As Range
Dim firstAddress As Range

'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Used to narrow down the logical operators for duplicates
Dim rngFirst As Range

'Set the ranges
rngFirst = Range("G" & 1, "G" & lw)

Set sh = Sheets("Completed")
lw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lw 'Find duplicates from the list.
'  If Application.CountIf(Range("A" & i & ":A" & lw), Range("A" & i).Text) = "Complete" Then
   If Range("A" & i).Text = "Complete" Then
   'if COMPLETE, check the rest of the sheet for any 'in progress' duplicates...
    With Worksheets("Still In Progress").rngFirst
      Set g = .Find(Range("G" & i).Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not g Is Nothing Then
          firstAddress = g.Address
          dupRow = firstAddress.Row
          If Range("H" & dupRow).Text = Range("H" & i).Text _
            And Range("I" & dupRow).Text = Range("I" & i).Text _
            And Range("J" & dupRow).Text = Range("J" & i).Text Then

            'select the entire row
            g.EntireRow.Select

            'copy the selection
            Selection.Cut

            'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
            Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")
            objNewSheet.Select

            'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
            Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

            Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'delete the initial row
            rngCell.EntireRow.Delete  ' <<<<<< the variable rngCell was never defined. Cannot guess what you wanted to do here!

            Do
              Set g = .FindNext(g)
              Loop While Not g Is Nothing And g.Address <> firstAddress

          End If ' entire row matched
        End If   ' Not g Is Nothing
      End With   ' With Worksheets("Still in Progress")
    End If       ' CountIf = "Complete"

  Next i

End Sub
```

Another handy trick: when you "paste in the next available row" as you are doing with `Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select`, I usually find it handy to do something like this instead:

```
Dim destination As Range
Set destination = Worksheets("Sheetname").Range("A1")
```

And when you need to paste something:

```
destination.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set destination = destination.Offset(1,0)
```

This way, `destination` is always pointing to the "next place where I can paste". I find it helpful and cleaner.